# Migrate directories and images from Linux to Amazon s3

Tags: amazon-s3, migration

I tried to migrate my Rails app images to s3 and it works perfectly (Rails 3, paperclip and s3 gem).

My problem is too find a solution to migrate my 200000 directories and images from my Linux server (CentOS) to s3 bucket.

I did lot of searches and didn't find an easy way to do this because there is not SSH or SCP commands available for s3 (with rsync).

1) I can use http://s3sync.net/ a ruby script but it seems quite complicate to use (installing OpenSSL, certificates...etc)

2) Somewhere I read that an option is too open an EC2 account to connect with SSH and migrate with rsync, then copy into S3 ? But this is not simple too.

I'm a little disapointed that there is not a simple way to migrate my data to s3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look as using S3FS. It allows you to mount your S3 bucket as a drive on a remote server.  You can then use linux command line to make the file copies.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will use this tool that looks like easier to use.